# Ubuntu One contacts with notes

Tags: ubuntu-one, facebook

There is a major issue with the notes section on the online contacts site after syncing with Facebook.

It seems to import fine however when I remove the text in the notes section it keeps bringing it back.

I have turned of sync now and I have to add a small character to everyone of the contacts for which notes were imported.

Is this a known issue and is there a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you no longer need to maintain the sync i.e. all your contacts are now in UbuntuOne you can disable sync and then simply delete all the notes from inside Evolution. This will eliminate the need to keep the single characters in the notes section.

Once this is done your updated Evolution files will take priority over your web  based copies and the notes from FB will never return.

I believe it has something to do with the way the notes from  Facebook sync with Ubuntu in the sense that you are not taking contact information only their picture, name and anything they have added to notes.

Hopefully FB and Ubuntu will do some kind of deal to allow the publishing of email addresses in the sync.